# Mysql query select in the same table

Tags: mysql, select

I have table people

```
Name               |       Score    |   Date

Don                |         A      |   12-10-2014              
Don                |         B      |   12-10-2014           
Mary               |         A      |   12-10-2014
Mary               |         C      |   12-10-2014
Mary               |         D      |   12-10-2014
Jack               |         A      |   12-10-2014
Jack               |         B      |   12-10-2014
Jack               |         C      |   12-10-2014
```

I want to get records which people with **score A and B**.

`Mary               |         A      |   12-10-2014`

will no be in the result because she doesn't have score B. The result must both have `A` and `B`.

So the output should be the following. Mary should not in the result because she only has score A

```
Name               |       Score    |   Date

Don                |         A      |   12-10-2014              
Don                |         B      |   12-10-2014          
Jack               |         A      |   12-10-2014
Jack               |         B      |   12-10-2014
```

I have tried the following query but the result is not right.

```
 select * 
 from people 
 where score='B' and Name in (select Name 
                              from people 
                              where score='A' 
                              group by Name)
```

Comment: WHERE score IN ('a','b') GROUP BY name HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT score) = 2;

Comment: the result is `Don A 1
Jack A 2`. Seems not right.

Comment: Well, it is right. If you want their complete results, just join the source table back on to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This subquery gets you the list of Name values with at least one Score of A and one of B.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.Name 
  FROM people AS a
  JOIN people AS b ON a.Name = b.Name AND a.score='A' AND b.score = 'B'
```

Then, you can join to the subquery to pull the records you need.

```
SELECT people.Name, people.Score, people.Date
  FROM people
  JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT a.Name 
          FROM people AS a
          JOIN people AS b ON a.Name = b.Name AND a.score='A' AND b.score = 'B'
       ) ab ON ab.Name = people.Name
 WHERE Score IN ('A','B')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do a self-join, something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM people p1 JOIN people p2 ON p1.name = p2.name WHERE p1.score = 'A' and p2.score = 'B'
```

Comment: the result is `Don A 1 Don B 2` 
`Jack A 2 Jack B 2` seems not right. How to get 4 records instead of 2?

Comment: To avoid returning unwanted columns, replace the `*` with the individual field names you need, e.g. `p1.name, p1.score, p1.date`.

To get the additional records, you could query for the score combination both ways round, e.g. `WHERE (p1.score = 'A' AND p2.score = 'B') OR (p1.score = 'B' and p2.score = 'A')`

Answer (score 1):

I think two `exists` clauses are perhaps the most logical approach:

```
select p.*
from people p
where score in ('A', 'B') and
      exists (select 1 from people p2 where p2.name = p.name and p2.score = 'A') and
      exists (select 1 from people p2 where p2.name = p.name and p2.score = 'B');
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Alias names will reduce the complexity and it seems much easy than using table names.
Here is the updated one with join to the subquery to pull the records needed as an extended and updated answer from @Olie's answer:

```
 SELECT P.Name AS Name, P.Score AS Score, P.Date AS Date
  FROM people P
  JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT P1.Name 
          FROM people P1
          JOIN people P2 ON P1.Name = P2.Name AND P1.score='A' AND P2.score = 'B'
       ) P3 ON P3.Name = P.Name
 WHERE P.Score IN ('A','B')
```